# How do I do a correct reverse-proxy to a Redis instance?

Tags: nginx, apache-2.4, docker, redis, docker-compose

I'm running an application called [Ambar](https://github.com/RD17/ambar/issues) on a (Samba)fileserver. I want users in my network to be able to search for documents freely, and securely. Since Ambar runs on HTTP, and the server already has Apache on it from before, I decided to set up a reverse proxy to Ambar through port 443. Should be quite straight-forward, one might think, but no, apparently Ambar (running on Redis) says the following:

`Possible SECURITY ATTACK detected. It looks like somebody is sending POST or Host: commands to Redis. This is likely due to an attacker attempting to use Cross Protocol Scripting to compromise your Redis instance. Connection aborted.`
 (taken from docker-compose logs).

I can reach the app's GUI, but I can't do anything there. That's a good thing anyway, since at least I know it's not a certificate issue..

This is my Apache-config:

```
LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so


<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName ambar.internal

    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://ambar.internal:1000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://ambar.internal:1000/

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/ambar.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/ambar.pem
</VirtualHost>
```

Edit: reverse-proxying with SSL/TLS activated from another machine does not work either.

Making manual modifications of Ambar packages isn't a great idea as the whole app comes with ready Docker containers. So my next attempt is to set up SSL in the `docker-compose.yml` file, but shouldn't there be a way to accomplish this with good-ol' reverse proxying?

Here is my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "2.1"
networks:
  internal_network:
services:
  db:
    restart: always
    networks:
      - internal_network
    image: ambar/ambar-mongodb:latest
    environment:
      - cacheSizeGB=2
    volumes:
      - /opt/ambar/db:/data/db
    expose:
      - "27017"
  es:
    restart: always
    networks:
      - internal_network
    image: ambar/ambar-es:latest
    expose:
      - "9200"
    environment:
      - cluster.name=ambar-es
      - ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms2g -Xmx2g
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
      nofile:
        soft: 65536
        hard: 65536
    cap_add:
      - IPC_LOCK
    volumes:
      - /opt/ambar/es:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
  rabbit:
    restart: always
    networks:
      - internal_network
    image: ambar/ambar-rabbit:latest
    hostname: rabbit
    expose:
      - "15672"
      - "5672"
    volumes:
      - /opt/ambar/rabbit:/var/lib/rabbitmq
  redis:
    restart: always
    sysctls:
      - net.core.somaxconn=1024
    networks:
      - internal_network
    image: ambar/ambar-redis:latest
    expose:
      - "6379"
  serviceapi:
    depends_on:
      redis:
        condition: service_healthy
      rabbit:
        condition: service_healthy
      es:
        condition: service_healthy
      db:
        condition: service_healthy
    restart: always
    networks:
      - internal_network
    image: ambar/ambar-serviceapi:latest
    expose:
      - "8081"
    environment:
      - mongoDbUrl=mongodb://db:27017/ambar_data
      - elasticSearchUrl=http://es:9200
      - redisHost=redis
      - redisPort=6379
      - rabbitHost=amqp://rabbit
      - langAnalyzer=ambar_en
  webapi:
    depends_on:
      serviceapi:
        condition: service_healthy
    restart: always
    networks:
      - internal_network
    image: ambar/ambar-webapi:latest
    expose:
      - "8080"
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    environment:
      - uiLang=en
      - mongoDbUrl=mongodb://db:27017/ambar_data
      - elasticSearchUrl=http://es:9200
      - redisHost=redis
      - redisPort=6379
      - serviceApiUrl=http://serviceapi:8081
      - rabbitHost=amqp://rabbit
  frontend:
    depends_on:
      webapi:
        condition: service_healthy
    image: ambar/ambar-frontend:latest
    restart: always
    networks:
      - internal_network
    ports:
      - "1000:80"
    expose:
      - "1000"
    environment:
      - api=http://192.168.123.123:8080
  pipeline0:
    depends_on:
      serviceapi:
        condition: service_healthy
    image: ambar/ambar-pipeline:latest
    restart: always
    networks:
      - internal_network
    environment:
      - id=0
      - apiUrl=http://serviceapi:8081
      - rabbit_host=amqp://rabbit
  documentation:
    depends_on:
      serviceapi:
        condition: service_healthy
    image: ambar/ambar-local-crawler
    restart: always
    networks:
      - internal_network
    expose:
      - "8082"
    environment:
      - name=documentation
      - ignoreExtensions=.{exe,dll,rar,s,so}
      - apiUrl=http://serviceapi:8081
    volumes:
      - /media/Documentation:/usr/data
```

Comment: What is on port 1000? Where is your `docker-compose.yml`?

Comment: Just added the `docker-compose.yml`-file. Ambar itself is running on port 1000, didn't want to mix it up with port 80.

Comment: That looks mostly like the example `docker-compose.yml`, but both are a little strange in that they expose ports that don't need to be exposed. All of the containers defined are always accessible to each other; ports that should be exposed are only those that need to be accessible from outside (like port 80 to reach the frontend or 8080 for the API). I'd start by removing unnecessary exposed ports. I would probably also raise an issue about the example with the developers.